# page not redirecting

Tags: php

```
                session_start(); 
            $_SESSION['fname']=$row['fname'];
        $_SESSION['user']=$row['name'];
        $_SESSION['adpoint'] = $row['adpoint'];
        $_SESSION['phone']=$row['phone'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Store some data in the session

        setcookie('smsapp',$_POST['rememberMe']);
        echo "your name"." ".$_SESSION['user'];

        Print_r ($_SESSION);
    header("Location: http://www.niktrixhosting.com/login/user/index.php");
```

here in this code header("Location: http://www.niktrixhosting.com/login/user/index.php");
this line is not redirecting it

plz mentionif any another function for redirecting page .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
echo "<script>window.location=\"http://www.niktrixhosting.com/login/user/index.php\"</script>";
```

instead of:

```
header("Location: http://www.niktrixhosting.com/login/user/index.php");
```

Comment: So that what he wants to happen works. even if he echo or display something before redirecting

Comment: @nicky, this is not a good solution. You're now not redirecting anyone who doesn't have Javascript, your redirect will go slower, and there's no reason to `echo` before a redirect anyway. Why print to a page that shouldn't even be displayed?

Answer (score 4):

You can't `echo` and `print_r` or give any other output before function `header`.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to set the headers after sending them. Comment out the `echo "your name"." ".$_SESSION['user'];` line and everything will work.

Explanation: The headers are always the first thing sent (that's why they're called headers). When you call `echo`, part of the page is sent, but if the headers aren't set, they will be sent first. What's happening in your code is that the `echo` line is sending the headers, and then you're trying to set them after the headers have already been sent (which doesn't work).

Answer (score 2):

Headers should be sent before any output, so any statement with an `echo` or a `print_r` before a header will cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

you are not to echo/print out/output anything before using header(). that will really affect your PHP page.